# unable to trigger jenkins build when code is pushed to gitlab

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, webhooks, jenkins-pipeline

when I am trying to use webhooks of gitlab to make a CI with Jenkins I am facing an issue with gitlab. when I push code to gitlab,  observed the errors in my logs as below from production.log

```
Started GET "/root/first1.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack" for 10.X.x.x. at 2017-02-16 13:
41:40 -0500
Processing by Projects::GitHttpController#info_refs as */*
  Parameters: {"service"=>"git-receive-pack", "namespace_id"=>"root", "project_id"=>"first1.git"}
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 20ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
Started GET "/root/first1.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack" for 10.X.x.x at 2017-02-16 13:
41:41 -0500
Processing by Projects::GitHttpController#info_refs as */*
  Parameters: {"service"=>"git-receive-pack", "namespace_id"=>"root", "project_id"=>"first1.git"}
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 17ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
Started GET "/root/first1.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack" for 10.x.x.x at 2017-02-16 13:
41:41 -0500
Processing by Projects::GitHttpController#info_refs as */*
  Parameters: {"service"=>"git-receive-pack", "namespace_id"=>"root", "project_id"=>"first1.git"}
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
Started POST "/root/first1.git/git-receive-pack" for 10.x.x.x at 2017-02-16 13:41:42 -0500
Processing by Projects::GitHttpController#git_receive_pack as application/x-git-receive-pack-result
  Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"root", "project_id"=>"first1.git"}
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
Started POST "/api/v3/internal/allowed" for 127.x.x.x at 2017-02-16 13:41:42 -0500
Started GET "/api/v3/internal/broadcast_message" for 127.x.x.x at 2017-02-16 13:41:42 -0500
Started GET "/api/v3/internal/merge_request_urls?project=/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/
first1.git&changes=1de706faf4e91b9f9264e114e12bdfdf16ff6d99%208b239d8f63c5db38a8d725baa62d5930371eea
fb%20refs/heads/master%0A" for 127.x.x.x. at 2017-02-16 13:41:42 -0500
WebHook Error => Failed to open TCP connection to 192.X.x.x.:8080 (getaddrinfo: Name or service
 not known)
Updating statistics for project 3
Scheduling removal of build artifacts
```

Comment: Minor code formatting - makes the logs more readable.

Comment: Are you using Jenkins pipelines at all? And how are you attempting to trigger builds in Jenkins from GitLab?

Comment: Have you installed this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitLab+Plugin

Comment: I used  gitlab project>integration> webhooks and I defined the url of Jenkins in gitlab webhooks section @PeterReid

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) - as I know it works, not too sure about the Gitlab plugin sorry.

Your webhook URL on GitLab should be set to:

```
http://jenkins.example.com/git/notifyCommit?url=https://gitlab.example.com/project/repository
```

Replace `https://gitlab.example.com/project/repository` with the URL of your git repository. You can get the URL by visiting the your repo in gitlab, and just copying the URL out of your browser URL bar.

This should trigger a build on Jenkins when the events you select occur.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your log:

> WebHook Error => Failed to open TCP connection to 192.X.x.x.:8080 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)

It seems a bit odd that what looks like a name resolution error occurs with an IP address, but generally it looks like you have some sort of networking issue that prevents your GitLab server from reaching the configured IP address and port.

Perhaps there's a firewall preventing outbound connections from the GitLab server, or the IP address of the Jenkins server in the webhook URL is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, I even tried to do telnet from both the servers gitlab and Jenkins. But finally I reconfigured the servers and then it started working well by giving http 200 response. As we are using chef to install this I destroyed the kitchen and then did kitchen converge. this helped me to fix this error.